# Android - Appium Swipe down not working

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, appium-android

I am trying to swipe down contact screen but its not working.

Here is the code I have tried.

```
public void Swipedown() throws InterruptedException
{
  // Select till which position you want to move the seekbar
  TouchAction action=new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
  Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();

  action.press(446,1404).moveTo(554,1500).release().perform(); 

    System.out.println("swipe down to set seekbar successfully");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

Can you guys help me what I am doing wrong here.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use below method for swiping down/up:

```
public static void swipeVertical(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
        Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int anchor = (int) (size.width * anchorPercentage);
        int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPercentage);
        int endPoint = (int) (size.height * finalPercentage);
        new TouchAction(driver).press(anchor, startPoint).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(anchor, endPoint).release().perform();
    }
```

Call above method by:

For scroll up: `swipeVertical((AppiumDriver)driver,0.9,0.1,0.5,3000);`

For scroll down: `swipeVertical((AppiumDriver)driver,0.1,0.9,0.5,3000);`

Comment: Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [swipeVertical] with [class io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver, double, double, double, int].

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to swipe up and down

```
TouchAction t=new TouchAction(driver);

//long press, for atleast 1 sec first and move the object

        WebElement First=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@***First Element Path***]");

        WebElement second=driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@***Second Element Path***]");
t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(First)).withDuration(ofSeconds(3))).moveTo(element(second)).release().perform();
```

Hope this helps :)