# Scroll in android app + appium with TouchActions

Tags: appium-android

I am doing automation testing on my Android app and am required to scroll in order to get visible the fields which are required to get scrolled.
I tried using the below code from [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/scroll/):

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.scroll(element, 10, 100);
action.perform();
```

After running this code it is giving me this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to
org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
```

Well, I know I've passed the driver in `TouchActions` which is of type `AndroidDriver`.

How would I fix this?

Comment: What do you want actually? Scrolling or Scroll to any specific element?

Comment: for now, I need scrolling. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Appium Swipe down not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636520/android-appium-swipe-down-not-working)

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636520/android-appium-swipe-down-not-working/50636622#50636622

Comment: well, it is giving me an error on the last line of the function where you have defined the TouchAction();
 "new TouchAction(driver).press(anchor, startPoint).waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration)).moveTo(anchor, endPoint).release().perform();"
that is  "The constructor TouchAction(AppiumDriver) is undefined"
can you please help me with this error.

Comment: You have to import `import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;`

Answer (score 0):

Please use TouchAction instead of TouchAction**s**

```
 TouchAction action = new TouchAction(androidDriver);
    int height = androidDriver.manage().window().getSize().height;
    int width = androidDriver.manage().window().getSize().width;
    action.press(PointOption.point(width / 2, height / 2))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(width / 2, height * 3 / 4)).release().perform();
```